# Initializing a struct containing a file

Tags: c, file, struct, initialization

I defined a simple struct like this:

```
typedef struct SGFile SGFile;
struct SGFile{
    FILE* sgf_file;
};
```

And a initialization function like this:

```
SGFile* sgf_file_new (void){
    GFile* sgf = {NULL};
    return sgf;
}
```

In my main, I try to initialize my function like this:

```
SGFile* sgf = sgf_file_new();
```

It's obviously not what I want to do, because sgf still points to NULL (0x000000).

My question is: what's the best practice to initialize a struct containing a FILE element?

Your help is very much appreciated.

Comment: What do you want this struct for? What's wrong with just using FILE*s normally with fopen(), etc.?

Comment: I'm starting a new project. I have already started adding some more variables to the struct. FLAGS mainly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think in your function `sgf_file_new`, you wanted to do this:

```
SGFile* sgf_file_new (void)
{
    GFile* sgf = (GFile*)malloc(sizeof(GFile));
    return sgf;
}
```

In fact, you only initialized the pointer with the value 0.

Comment: You're welcome. ;-) Please don't forget to validate the response if you're okay with it. ^^

Comment: I was gonna :) Apparently you have to wait for 15mins before validating an answer. In all cases now it's done.